# ireports crosstab dosen't display

Tags: jasper-reports, crosstab

I have a problem with iReports 5.5.0 crosstab. I use following query:

```
SELECT
to_char("AGG_DATE", 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS day,
to_char("AGG_DATE", 'HH24') AS hour,
"AGG_AVERAGE_TIME" AS general_avg
FROM "LCT_AGGREGATES"
WHERE "AGG_PRJ_DESC" = $P{Project_Code_sub}
AND "AGG_DATE">=to_timestamp($P{Date_from_sub}, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND "AGG_DATE"<to_timestamp($P{Date_to_sub}, 'yyyy-mm-dd') ORDER BY 1 ASC
```

And I can display line chart correctly. The chart has ~30 series, x is hour (so 24 points) and y is value (general_avg).

The problem is when I try to generate crosstab for that chart. I wanted hour(rows), day(columns) but it doesn't work. I use the same dataset but the crosstab doesn't appear at all. Where's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I was managed to do it. Just remember to map you input parameters in crosstab